# real-valued function in python

Tags: python

I want to create real-valued function program the Question is

Write a Python program to compute a real-valued function f(x) where the argument x is a real number.

- `if x <= 15` Use formula 2x + 10
- `if x > 15 and x <= 35` Use formula 3x**2
- `else:` Use formula 2x**3 - 5
  The program reads the value of x from the user and prints the computed value of the function with 3 decimal points on the screen.

Your program must have the following functions:

`f`: receive parameter x and return value of f(x)

`display_f`: receive parameters of two values, value of x and value of f(x). Use these two values to display result on screen.

EX when run program :

shell mode

```
 >>> f(31.039)
2890.2585630000003
>>> f(42.103)
149263.82765345403
>>>
```

output

EX1

```
Enter a real number: 10
f(10.000) = 30.000
```

EX2

```
Enter a real number: 21.5
f(21.500) = 1386.750
```

EX3

```
Enter a real number: 51.73
f(51.730) = 276853.225
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can incorporate the conditions into the function:

```
def f(x):
    if x <= 15:
        return x * 2 + 10
    if x <= 35:
        return 3 * x ** 2
    return 2 * x**3 - 5
```

When calling the function:

```
>>> f(31.039)
2890.2585630000003
>>> f(42.103)
149263.82765345403
>>>
```

For the `display_f`:

```
def f(x):
    if x <= 15:
        return x * 2 + 10
    if x <= 35:
        return 3 * x ** 2
    return 2 * x**3 - 5
number = float(input("Enter a real number: "))
num = '{:.3f}'.format(number)
display_f = f"f({num}) = {'{:.3f}'.format(round(f(number), 3))}"
print(display_f)
```

Output:

```
Enter a real number: 51.73
f(51.730) = 276853.225
```